# Build a modal with a "do not show again" checkbox in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, local-storage

I'm working in a Angular project (version 16) and I'd like to build a dialog modal with a "do not show again" checkbox.
The process would be this one :

- a user visits the web application. At his first connection, a dialog modal appears with the "do not show again" checkbox
- the user reads the content of the modal and chooses to check the checkbox
- if the user visits the web app some minutes later, the dialog modal no longer appear because the browser stores the previous choice of user to "do not show again"

I read some stuff about the LocalStorage fonctionnality but don't know how to build it in Angular.

Here is my code for the moment :

**TS :**

```
openDialog() {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent);

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
  });
}
```

**HTML (Angular-Material UI) :**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>My dialog modal</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">

<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First">First</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second">Second</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Do not show again</mat-checkbox>

</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>Install</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Have you any ideas to complete this ?
Any help would be thankly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT :**

**Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztwqs2?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo to explain what I'd like to do.**

Answer (score 2):

You can save to local storage a string value when the user clicks the "do not show again" checkbox

and before opening the modal check in local storage if that value is saved

Code example:

```
openDialog() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('doNtShowAgain')) return;

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result.doNtShow) { // change this to match the checkbox
            localStorage.setItem('doNtShowAgain', '1')
        }
        console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers provided are correct on the usage of `localStorage` however, none of them are providing a complete implementation for your example stackblitz.

***As mentioned in other answers provided, below is the proper API to set and retrieve a value from local storage.***

> Retrieve value:
>
> ```
> const firstVisit = localStorage.getItem('firstVisit');
> ```
>
> set value:
>
> ```
> localStorage.setItem('firstVisit', result);`
> ```

***With regard to your question about how to properly retrieve the checkbox value from the `mat-dialog`.***

The `mat-dialog-close` directive receives an input to be returned as a "result" value once the `afterClosed` subscription emits. To use it, one possible solution would be as follows.

Set a template reference for your checkbox in your dialog markup via `#checkBox`.

```html
<mat-checkbox #checkBox class="example-margin">Do not show me again</mat-checkbox>
```

You can then use that template reference to pass the `checked` value to your `mat-dialog-close` directive like this `[mat-dialog-close]="checkBox.checked"`.

```html
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="checkBox.checked">OK</button>
```

Don't forget the bang on your if statement here; you only want to open the dialog if local storage value is `falsey`.

```
 // only open dialog if falsey
    if (!firstVisit) {
      this.openDialog2();
    }
```

Please see a working StackBlitz example below.

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vacnzu?file=src%2Fmodal-dialog%2Fmodal-dialog.component.html

Comment: This is effectively how I do it for an annual popup. Every year I store the year last displayed so that when the next year rolls around, if currentYear !== lastYearDisplayed, boom.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to know how to access localStorage? If that is the case, the syntax is just this:

*To set a localStorage item:*

```
localStorage.setItem('show-dialog', 'no');
```

*To get a localStorage item:*

```
localStorage.getItem('show-dialog');
```

Keep in mind that localStorage items are stored as strings, so you would need to do some conversion to convert the string to a boolean value. Something like this:

```
showDialog: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.showDialog = localStorage.getItem('show-dialog') == 'no' ? false : true;
}
```

On first load, if the localStorage item is not present, then the dialog will be shown. If the user clicks on the checkbox, just set the localStorage item to 'no' or something like that.

EDIT: Here is an example of a small service that can manage your subscriptions.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  private showChangedSource: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  showChanged$ = this.showChangedSource.asObservable();

  changeShowValue(show: boolean) {
    this.showChangedSource.next(show);
  }
  
}
```

And, in your component with the checkbox:

```
checkboxControl = new UntypedFormControl();

constructor(private service: MyService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.checkboxControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.service.changeShowValue(value);
  }
}
```

And, in your component that you want to know when the checkbox changed:

```
constructor(private service: MyService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.showChanged$.subscribe(show => {
    // Add logic to do something with the value from the checkbox
    console.log('do not show value: ', show);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer. I now understand but how could I do to get the value of the checkbox "do not show again" back from ModalDialogComponent to my TS component file ?

Comment: I personally am a fan of using a small singleton service to manage these types of things. In the service you can set up observables that can be triggered from anywhere in your application and send a message to the subscriber on change. I will edit my response to include an example of one of these services.

Answer (score 0):

On initialization you have to load the boolean **firstVisit** then you check if it is true, it means you need to show the dialog

Your main component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const firstVisit = localStorage.getItem('firstVisit');
    if(firstVisit){
      this.openDialog();
    }  
  }
```

And you also need to store the validation value if the user clicks accept

```
 openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent);
  
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        localStorage.setItem('firstVisit', result);
        console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

Basically, you can store data in local storage using:

```
localStorage.setItem('variableName', value);
```

Read data from local storage using:

```
localStorage.getItem('variableName');
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer. I now understand but how could I do to get the value of the checkbox "do not show again" back from ModalDialogComponent to my TS component file ?

Comment: @Julien if you share your code on stackblitz it will be more easier

Comment: Yes you're right. I tried to do it but everytime I had problems of compilation because of Angular material modules... I will keep on trying and send you a link. Thanks

Comment: Hi, here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztwqs2?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) code. Could you take a look at that ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a very simple way, You have to just check that user checked the `do not show again` checkbox or not with irresepect to first connection or not.

***How to check if user checked the `do not show again` checkbox or not previously ?***

You can set the flag for the `checkbox` value in a localStorage on click of `Install` icon.

```
onInstall() {
   // you can get the checkbox value from the `ng-model` attribute.
   // Just for the explanation I am assuming user selected the checkbox and I am getting a `true`.
   const checkboxValue = true; // replace `true` with ng-model variable.
   localStorage.setItem('isdoNotShowAgainCheckBoxSelected', checkboxValue)
}
```

Now, When user visit the application again, You can check for the localStorage value in `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook to perform the action to `show/hide` the dialog.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const isCheckBoxSelected = localStorage.getItem('isdoNotShowAgainCheckBoxSelected');
    if(!isCheckBoxSelected) {
      this.openDialog();
    }
}
```